# How to resize UIView for universal application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame, autoresize

I've added `UIView` of iPhone layout, within the XIB, now I'm converting whole app for iPad too. What's the best way to reframe (resize) those added `UIView`s into XIB. I've autoresized for each of view,

This how I am doing,

```
- (Void) addTempView {
    [scrollViewMain addSubview:viewTemp];
    viewTemp.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewTemp.frame.size.width, viewTemp.frame.size.height);
}
```

I'm calling this in`viewDidLoad`, its working fine with iPhone, but not with iPad, as `viewTemp` is of iPhone layout, that's (width 320, height 200). Its not autoresizing automatically.

I know, I can do that with `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.frame`, is there any other way? as I've to change at many places bacause of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize your view programmatically you can use the following code :

```
#define IS_IPAD()       (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE5()    ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Size of the view
    if (IS_IPAD())
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.frame = (IS_IPHONE5() ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568) : CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480));
    }
}
```

or in unique line of code :

```
self.view.frame = (IS_IPAD() ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024) : (IS_IPHONE5() ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568) : CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)));
```

Here, you resize your view for iPad screen or iPhone 5 screen or iPhone 4 scree.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, can't it possible without making any changes in the code? Also, I don't want to resize self.view, its resizing automatically, if I set its type to `Freeform`, and auto resized. I've to resize views which is inside that particular view (added in XIB).

Comment: I gave you an example for resizing `UIView` depending of iPad and iPhone. Adapt this code with your viewTemp for example and so replace self.view by self.viewTemp. You can also change the frame inside CGrectMake